# How to find the last row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Currently i'm working on the jqgrid, where i have to find out the last row and implement the ctrl down functionality. But currently i could not able to get the last row.

Needed some one help here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `.find('.selector').last()`?

Answer (score 4):

If the grid id is for example `list` then the following expression should return you the last row:

```js
$("#list").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:last");
```

or

```js
$("#list").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow").filter(":last");
```

One more, event better, way to get the last row is the following

```js
var rows = $("#list")[0].rows,
    lastRowDOM = rows[rows.length-1];
```

It uses the [rows](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) collection of DOM representation of `<table>`. The value `$(lastRowDOM)` will the same as `$("#list").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow").filter(":last")`.

Answer (score 0):

For 4.6.0 version above

$("#list tbody:first tr:nth-child(2)").attr('id');

For me working fine using 4.6.0 version