# How to find the id of the last row in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Currently i'm working on the jqgrid, where i have to find out the id of the last row and implement the  But currently i could not able to get the id of the last row.

Needed some one help here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('table').find('tbody tr:last').get(0).id`

Comment: how and where do you want it? also post some code if you have tried something. although you can tweak little A.wolff's comment line actually that is an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the grid id is for example list then the following expression should return you the last row:

```
$("#list").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:last");
```

or

```
$("#list").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow").filter(":last");
```

One more, event better, way to get the last row is the following

```
var rows = $("#list")[0].rows,
    lastRowDOM = rows[rows.length-1];
```

It uses the rows collection of DOM representation of . The value $(lastRowDOM) will the same as `$("#list").find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow").filter(":last").`

To get the `id`, you simply have to do : `lastRowDOM .attr('id');`

The answer itself has been obtained from this thread : [How to find the last row in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214213/how-to-find-the-last-row-in-jqgrid)

So, all the Kudos to the person who originally posted it.

Comment: You should use the "close" option on the question and post the link for the duplicate thread, rather than answer it again and clutter up the site with dupes.

Comment: @Archer : I did not do that, because, the question was not: how to get the last row, rather , it was : how to get the `id ` of the last row. So , i have a small piece of code, that was not present in that thread, which begets the ID and thus accurately answers the question posted by the OP.

Comment: TUVM!! You helped me!

Comment: @user1501754 : Glad to have helped.